# How to groupBy() Eloquent collection by column?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a program table that refers to location, major, grade, type table. I want to group programs based on their location to major and type collection. I can group them by garde_id, but I want to have a grade name instead of grade id.

```php
$programs = Program::whereLocation_id($location->id)
    ->with('location', 'department', 'major', 'grade')
    ->latest()->get();

$programs->groupBy('grade_id');
```

**Result**

```
[
    1 => ['department-name','major-name','title'],
    2 => ['department-name','major-name','title']
]
```

**Expected**

```
[
  'phd' => ['department-name','major-name','title'],
  'M.S' => ['department-name','major-name','title']
]
```

What is the best query to accomplish this in Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve programs from grades and you'll have the expected result.
I guess the relationship name in Grade model is called 'programs'

```
$locationId = $location->id;
$grades = Grade::whereHas('programs', function($query) use ($locationId) {
    $query->where('location_id', $locationId);
})->with(['programs' => function ($query) use ($locationId) {
    $query->where('location_id', $locationId);
    $query->with('location','department','major');

    return $query;
}])->get();
```

You will have a collection of grades which each have their programs in it.
You can also group by grades name:

```
$grades->groupBy('name');
```

Comment: This seems kind of work, I will test it and let the others know. Thank u for your response.

Comment: This query has one problem, It returns all grades, even grades which hasn't any programs. I want to remove them.

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy Check the answer again. I added ´whereHas´ to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for your case would be:

```
$grouped = $programs->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['grade']->name; // Setting grade name as key
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because we haven't 'grade' in our items we have grade_id

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy You added the 'grade' relationship `->with('location', 'department', 'major', 'grade')`, so I think $item['grade'] or $item->grade should give you that.

Comment: hmm, but it doesn't. It seem groupBy doesn't work on relation items.